# How to export Django model data into CSV file

Tags: python, django, csv

I want to export all my model data into CSV file :

models.py

```
import ast
import uuid
import base64
from django.db import models
from django.contrib import admin
from qlu.settings import HOST_NAME,STATS_URI
from django.core.validators import URLValidator
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------ 


class short_url(models.Model):
    """
        This is a short_url class 
    """
    blocked = models.BooleanField(default=False)                                # To check whether URL is blocked or not 
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)                            # When URL is updated
    url = models.TextField(validators=[URLValidator()])                         # URL entered by the user
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)                        # When URL is created
    url_hash = models.CharField(max_length=10,unique=True,db_index=True)        # base64 encoded URL id  

    def _generateShortUrl(self):
        """
            This function will generate base64 encoded URL hash
        """
        hash = base64.urlsafe_b64encode(uuid.uuid1().bytes)[:6]
        hash_exist = short_url.objects.filter(url_hash=hash)
        while hash_exist:
            hash = base64.urlsafe_b64encode(uuid.uuid1().bytes)[:6]
            hash_exist = short_url.objects.filter(url_hash=hash)        
            continue       
        return hash 


    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        """
            Custom Save method for link model 
        """
        self.url_hash = self._generateShortUrl()        
        super(short_url, self).save(*args, **kwargs)    


    def get_short_url(self):
        """
            This method returns the url_hash related to the url 
        """
        return HOST_NAME + self.url_hash

    def get_stats_url(self):
        """
            This method returns the stats page URL for a url_hash
        """        
        return HOST_NAME + self.url_hash + STATS_URI


    def __unicode__(self):
        """
            This method convert Django model object to the user readable string 
        """
        return unicode(self.url)


class click_info(models.Model):
    """
        This is a click_info class 
    """
    user_ip = models.TextField()                                                # Store the user_ip
    user_agent = models.TextField()                                             # Store the user_agent
    http_refrer = models.TextField()                                            # Store the http_refrer
    hash = models.ForeignKey(short_url)                                         # base64 encoded URL id
    get_parameters = models.TextField()                                         # Store other get_parameters
    request_time = models.DateTimeField()                                       # When user made the request_time
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)                            # When click_info is updated
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)                        # When click is created


    def get_parameters_dict(self):
        """
            This method returns the get parameter dict
        """
        return ast.literal_eval(self.get_parameters)


    def __unicode__(self):
        """
            This method convert Django model object to the user readable string 
        """
        return unicode(self.hash)


#------------------------------------------------------------------------------ 

class short_url_admin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    """
        short_url_admin class
    """
    list_display = ('url','blocked','updated_at',
                    'created_at','url_hash')
    exclude = ('url_hash',)


class url_info_admin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    """
        url_info_admin class
    """
    list_display = ('user_ip','user_agent','http_refrer',
                    'hash','request_time','get_parameters_dict')    

#------------------------------------------------------------------------------ 
admin.site.register(short_url,short_url_admin)
admin.site.register(click_info,url_info_admin)
```

What is the best way to do this ..?

Comment: You should probably read https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/outputting-csv/. Combine that with .objects.all() and I think you have solution.

Comment: I created a Class based view to help in organizing CSV views in python https://github.com/dm03514/django-cbv-toolkit

Comment: https://github.com/azavea/django-queryset-csv

Comment: @ChemicalProgrammer thanks

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I usually prefer an action for this in the admin. This is the [snippet](http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/2690/):

```
def download_csv(modeladmin, request, queryset):
    if not request.user.is_staff:
        raise PermissionDenied
    opts = queryset.model._meta
    model = queryset.model
    response = HttpResponse(mimetype='text/csv')
    # force download.
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment;filename=export.csv'
    # the csv writer
    writer = csv.writer(response)
    field_names = [field.name for field in opts.fields]
    # Write a first row with header information
    writer.writerow(field_names)
    # Write data rows
    for obj in queryset:
        writer.writerow([getattr(obj, field) for field in field_names])
    return response
download_csv.short_description = "Download selected as csv"
```

To use it in your view function

```
def myview(request):
    data = download_csv(ModelAdmin, request, Model.objects.all())

    return HttpResponse (data, content_type='text/csv')
```

Comment: This did not work for me. Can python3 be the reason? The error is 'The view app1.views.bulk_download didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.

Answer (score 12):

Hi you can simply do it

**views.py**

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
import csv

def export_users_csv(request):
    response = HttpResponse(content_type='text/csv')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="users.csv"'

    writer = csv.writer(response)
    writer.writerow(['employee','IG', 'follower', 'email', 'website', 'DA', 'youtube_url', 'youtube_name', 'subscriber', 'type','country'])

    users = Library.objects.all().values_list('employee','IG', 'follower', 'email', 'website', 'DA', 'youtube_url', 'youtube_name', 'subscriber', 'type','country')
    for user in users:
        writer.writerow(user)

    return response
```

**urls.py**

```
from .views import export_users_csv

path('export', export_users_csv, name='export_users_csv'),
```

**page.html**

```
<a href="{% url 'export_users_csv' %}">Export all users</a>
```

Comment: This is the most complete solution.

Comment: You don't need the `page.html`. Using the `urls.py` above, you can just visit `/export` and it will respond with the CSV file download

Answer (score 12):

Here is an updated and version of @symbiotech answer for `Python 3`.
Inspired by [this snippet](https://djangosnippets.org/snippets/2690/) and [this article](http://blog.aeguana.com/2015/12/12/csv-export-data-for-django-model/)

---

**utils.py**

```
def download_csv(request, queryset):
  if not request.user.is_staff:
    raise PermissionDenied

  model = queryset.model
  model_fields = model._meta.fields + model._meta.many_to_many
  field_names = [field.name for field in model_fields]

  response = HttpResponse(content_type='text/csv')
  response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="export.csv"'

  # the csv writer
  writer = csv.writer(response, delimiter=";")
  # Write a first row with header information
  writer.writerow(field_names)
  # Write data rows
  for row in queryset:
      values = []
      for field in field_names:
          value = getattr(row, field)
          if callable(value):
              try:
                  value = value() or ''
              except:
                  value = 'Error retrieving value'
          if value is None:
              value = ''
          values.append(value)
      writer.writerow(values)
  return response
```

**views.py**

```
def export_csv(request):
  # Create the HttpResponse object with the appropriate CSV header.
  data = download_csv(request, Publication.objects.all())
  response = HttpResponse(data, content_type='text/csv')
  return response
```

If you want to export from the admin panel. With the following code, you can select the items and export from the dropdown "Export selected items to CSV".

**admin.py**

```
def export_csv(modeladmin, request, queryset):
    return download_csv(request, queryset)

export_csv.short_description = "Export selected items to CSV"

@admin.register(MyModel)
    class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
        ...
        actions = (export_csv,)
```

Answer (score 0):

Tweaked one line. To avoid returning AttributeError exceptions, you can add in a default value of None if the attribute doesn't exist.

```
writer.writerow([getattr(obj, field, None) for field in field_names])
```

Answer (score 0):

Another quick and simple approach is to use the pandas library.

```
import pandas as pd

...

def export_csv(request):
  df = pd.DataFrame(o.__dict__ for o in MyModel.objects.all())
  df.to_csv("/my/path/my_filename.csv")
  return HttpResponse("<p>Done!</p>")
```